# What does "take a nap between the snoozing lion and lamb" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, phrases, phrasal-verbs, idiomatic-language

This phrase is from the below paragraph in the book *Behave: The Biology of Humans at Our Best and Worst* by Robert M. Sapolsky.

> The book has a number of personal roots. One is that, having had
>   blessedly little personal exposure to violence in my life, the entire
>   phenomenon scares the crap out of me. I think like an academic
>   egghead, believing that if I write enough paragraphs about a scary
>   subject, give enough lectures about it, it will give up and go away
>   quietly. And if everyone took enough classes about the biology of
>   violence and studied hard, **we’d all be able to take a nap between
>   the snoozing lion and lamb**. Such is the delusional sense of efficacy
>   of a professor.

Comment: Welcome to the community, @sb1  I hope you find it enjoyable, interesting and valuable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lovely turn of phrase, invented by the author but (as noted in the comment by @Hellion below) with a biblical reference.

The phrase signifies the author's wishful thinking about a world free of violence and aggression.

In that imaginary world, a gentle little lamb could play safely in a meadow while a big lion snoozed nearby, with no intention of attacking the lamb.  Meanwhile, we could drift into a light sleep on the grass in between the two, unconcerned about the lion's aggression or the lamb's vulnerability.

In the real world, of course, a lion on seeing a lamb (a totally vulnerable creature, having no capacity for either aggression or flight) would race towards it and pounce!  The lamb would be an ex-lamb in mere moments.  We would be (at best) mere silent witnesses; at worst we would be caught up in the aggression.

Comment: It's also a reference to Paradise as seen in the Old Testament (apparently a misquote/paraphrase from the book of Isaiah); "then the lion shall lay down with the lamb, and a little child shall lead them".  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lamb_and_lion).

Comment: @Hellion - Thanks!  That's an excellent point.   I had suspected there was an intertextual reference in the phrase, and of course that's the one!

Comment: @Hellion - And I've just edited my answer to make a reference to your comment.